# Interpretation of results in non-inferiority study

Tags: confidence-interval, interpretation, clinical-trials

I need some help interpreting some results from a non-inferiority study.  The primary endpoint for assessment of non-inferiority is the change from baseline in Power of Attention Score.  The study is looking to show that the new treatment is no worse than placebo in its impact on a patient's cognitive function.  The non-inferiority limit is 121ms.

Results from the analyses show a difference between treatment groups of 23.23ms in terms of increases from baseline in power of attention score (Placebo-Treatment), so the new treatment is showing a smaller increase from baseline than placebo.  The 95% CI for this difference is (-145.1,191.59). Given that the mean increase from baseline was smaller in the new treatment group and the upper limit of the 95% CI is < 121ms (non-inferiority limit), then I assume we can conclude non-inferiority (i.e. any advantage in placebo is less than non-inferiority limit) as the CI lies to the left of the limit?

I am asking this question as I am a little confused on whether to be using the upper bound of lower bound of the non-inferiority interval. The 95% CI does in fact include the lower limit.  Also, the CI is very wide so I am wondering how valid this conclusion is anyway based on the number of patients included in the analysis.

Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of noninferiority and equivalence is to reverse the null and alternative hypothesis.  So the null hypothesis is set to conclude inferiority and the alternative is non-inferiority.  The study should be powered to have a high probability to reject inferiority when the difference is less than the limit.  So you want the lower bound of your one-sided 95% confidence interval to be greater then -121 Your lower limit is NOT GREATER than -121 so you cannot conclude non-inferiority!

It does not appear that you powered the study to reject inferiority because even though the observed performance for the new treatment was numerically better than for teh old the conifidence interval was too wide to declare noninferiority.  The problem is probably that the sample size is too small and teh study is underpowered rather than that the new treatment is actually inferior to the old one.