# Inconclusive results in non-inferiority design

Tags: non-inferiority

I am interested in how an inconclusive result occurs given the formal null and alternative hypotheses required for non-inferiority testing.

I have pre-specified a noninferiority design comparing accepted and experimental treatments. The design tests the null hypothesis that experimental treatment is harmful and alternative hypothesis that treatment is noninferior to accepted treatment. The noninferiority margin was prespecified as a difference of not more than 2.9% mortality (experimental - accepted). I obtained the result of a mortality difference of 0.9% (95% CI of -2.5%,13.6%).

I am reading [here](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/fullarticle/1487502) that this result is inconclusive. I cannot reconcile the inconclusive result in the setting of the hypothesis tests. It seems that I can neither reject my null hypothesis nor accept the alternative based on my result. From a conservative standpoint, it seems that if the upper boundary of the 95% CI exceeds the prespecified noninferiority margin that the null hypothesis cannot be rejected.

How can an inconclusive result be possible given the formal null and alternative hypotheses? Is a third hypothesis necessary for these types of studies?

This has been tangentially addressed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37421/interpretation-of-results-in-non-inferiority-study), as  a matter of lack of power. In my case, I understand that a lack of power exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you show, you fail to reject the null hypothesis. This is like any other case, where you fail to reject it. This does not mean that you accept it - i.e. it is entirely possible that the null hypothesis is false, but you cannot reject it at the one-sided 2.5% signignificance level with the present data. So the result is inconclusive.

This is not different from any other case of null hypothesis testing, the only difference is that your null hypothesis is $\delta \leq 2.9$%, while very often we look at $\delta \leq 0$ or for two-sided testing at $\delta = 0$. What would be your interpretation of the data you obtained, if that had been your null hypothesis?

It is certainly true, that your example may look like a case of low power. Especially, if up-front it was believe that the two treatments are approximately equivalent, then clearly the study was too small or short to observe enough deaths to have any reasonable power with this non-inferiority margin.

Comment: Why is failure to reject the null inconclusive in this case? Failure to reject seems like a valid result of the noninferiority design. In a standard 2-sided test of H0 = 0 we don't claim an inconclusive result if the confidence interval crosses 0.

Comment: It's a valid result. If we fail to reject the H0 for a standard 2-sided test of H0=0, that is also inconclusive (we do not really know whether the H0 is true or not, we just could not reject it). In addition, with non-inferiority, there is the possibility that you get another kind of conclusive result: You may fail to find non-inferiority and infact demonstrate inferiority (i.e. the standard treatment is clearly superior to the new treatment). I assume that might be what such a comment refers to. One might also get both non-inferiority & superiority to the accepted treatment.